# how to enter into visual block mode in evil on windows?

Tags: key-bindings, microsoft-windows, evil

in VIM on MS Windows, I could use `C-q` to enter into visual block mode. How about in evil? I tried the same but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never heard of `C-q` to enter visual block, not even on Windows. The default binding for that, AFAIK, is `C-v`, and that also applies to evil. But if you wish you can bind visual block to `C-q` with

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "\C-q" 'evil-visual-block)
```

Comment: `C-q` is actually bound to Visual Block Mode in GVim. I just checked.

Comment: You're right, I just checked myself. After years using vim I've never used it. But I think `C-v` makes more sense because all visual modes are focused on `v`